# Get latest always give me "A non version controlled file or writable file by the same name already exists locally"

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Thanks in advance.
Visual Studio 2017, Windows 10.

Doing a get latest always brings up:  "A non version controlled file or writable file by the same name already exists.".

We don't have gated check-ins for any builds.  Each time I do a get I always select "Overwrite Local File or Folder".  I've even deleted the top level folder on my file system and did a brand new get (Advanced | Get Specific Version | checked both check boxes),  of everything, and yet anytime a file changes I am prompted with the same dialog.  I've checked Tools | Options to see if there's a get writable setting but I haven't found one.
The files on the file system are not read only.  This happens on both my local machine and on the build server (WinServer 2012, VS 2017).

This is very problematic.  Does anyone know how I can get past this?

Thanks.

K.J.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the latest version from TFS and keep the local files (if they're your latest work).
Then check-in again without any problems.

(I made a copy of the project before getting the latest version, just in case)